# How to update cell reference values using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to create new XSSFWorkbook from an existing one, after updating some values. Suppose I have two worksheets (Lets say: worksheet A & B) in my existing workbook. Worksheet B has some cell reference from Worksheet A. IF i modify those cell values of worksheet A and save them as a new workbook, corresponding cell values of worksheet B should be updated too. But it doesn't. How can i update them programmatically? . Thank you.

My code:

```
public  void createExcel(ClientData cd) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InvalidFormatException{
            // create a new file
        double[] dataHolder1= cd.getFinalData1(),  param1 = cd.getRecord1Param();
        double[] dataHolder2 = cd.getFinalData2(), param2 = cd.getRecord2Param();
        double[] ncv = cd.getNcv();
        String[] pname = cd.getName();
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(OPCPackage.open(new FileInputStream("template/mncv.xlsx"))); // or sample.xls
            //CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
            Sheet s=workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            int counter = dataHolder1.length + param1.length +param2.length+dataHolder2.length;//+ param1.length + param2.length;
//            r = s.getRow(0);
//            r.getCell(0).setCellValue("Param1");
//            r.getCell(1).setCellValue("Record1");
//            r.getCell(2).setCellValue("Param2");
//            r.getCell(3).setCellValue("Record2");

            int i;
            for(i=0;i<counter;i++){
                if(i<param1.length){
                    for(int j=0;j<param1.length;j++){
                        r = s.getRow(i);
                        r.getCell(0).setCellValue(param1[j]);
                        i++;
                    }
                }else if(i<dataHolder1.length+param1.length && i>=param1.length){

                    for(int j=0;j<dataHolder1.length;j++){
                        r = s.getRow(i);
                        r.getCell(0).setCellValue(dataHolder1[j]);
                        i++;
                    }

                }else if(i<dataHolder1.length+param1.length+param2.length && i>=dataHolder1.length+param1.length){
                    for(int j=0;j<param2.length;j++){
                        r = s.getRow(i);
                        r.getCell(0).setCellValue(param2[j]);
                        i++;
                    }
                }else{
                    for(int j=0;j<dataHolder2.length;j++){
                        r = s.getRow(i);
                        r.getCell(0).setCellValue(dataHolder2[j]);
                        i++;
                    }
                }

//                if(i<=param1.length){
//                    r.getCell(0).setCellValue(param1[i-1]);
//                    r.getCell(2).setCellValue(param2[i-1]);
//
//                }
                // r.getCell(0).setCellValue(param1[i]);
                 //r.getCell(3).setCellValue(dataHolder2[i-1]);
                i--;
            }
            for(int k=0;k<ncv.length;k++){
                r = s.getRow(i);
                r.getCell(0).setCellValue(ncv[k]);
                i++;
            }

            s = workbook.getSheetAt(1);

            s.getRow(2).getCell(5).setCellValue(pname[0]+" "+pname[1]+" "+pname[2]);
            s.getRow(3).getCell(5).setCellValue(cd.getAge());
            s.getRow(4).getCell(5).setCellValue(cd.getGender());


 try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx")) { 
     //WorkbookEvaluator we = new WorkbookEvaluator(workbook); 

            workbook.write(out);     
            out.close();
          XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells((XSSFWorkbook) workbook);

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Excel file format caches the result of formula evaluation, to make opening the file quicker. This means that when you're done making changes to your file, you'll need to evaluate all of the formula cells to updated their cached value. (Otherwise, when you load the file in Excel, for almost all cases it'll still show the old value until you go into that cell)

Luckily, Apache POI provides code to do that, see the [Formula Evaluation documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) for details. (You can choose to only recalculate certain formulas, if you know just those cells have changed, or do everything)

Comment: Thanks! Its working. I used the below mentioned function to update the whole workbook as it has many functions and cell references.  
`XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells((XSSFWorkbook) workbook);`

Comment: This did not wok  for me.

Answer (score 0):

For any cell, say "B5", at runtime,

```
cell.getReference();
```

will give you cell reference (like in example... it will return you "B5")

```
cell.getReference().toString().charAt(0);
```

will give you the Column Reference (will give you "B" if the current cell is B5). Now

```
cell.getRowIndex();
```

OR
     cell.getReference().toString().charAt(1);

will give you Row Index. Now you have the reference of the target cell. just replace these character with the references you have already created. This will update the cell references.

Comment: I Think I was not clear enough to explain my problem. Let me try again:
suppose B5 of worksheet2 is the cell reference of A5 of worksheet 1.
If current value of A5 is 10, B5 value will be 10 too. If I change the value of A5 to 15 using apache POI, B5 value should be updated as 15. But B5 value still remains to 10. This is the problem I am currently having. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me

```
wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
// replace "wb" with your HSSFWorkbook/XSSFWorkbook object
```