# Iterating Excel Spreadsheet values POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a Java program that needs to read an excel file with a specific range that contains data, say from C6 to I6. The total number of rows will vary.
After which, I want to save these data into an object, and eventually into a list.
Here is an example (data start from row 6. In this case, the last row of data ends at row 10):

```
          ---------------------------------------------------------------------
          | C      | D       | E       | F       | G       | H       | I      |       
          ---------------------------------------------------------------------
(row 6)   |  001   |10102011 | 874837  | Y       | Y       | TEST001 | No     |
          ---------------------------------------------------------------------
(row 7)   |  002   |11102011 | 8743834 | Y       | Y       |         | No     |
          ---------------------------------------------------------------------
(row 8)   |  003   |15102011 | 609348  | N       | Y       |         | No     |    
          ---------------------------------------------------------------------
(row 9)   |  004   |20102011 | 111117  | N       | Y       |         | No     |
          ---------------------------------------------------------------------
(row 10)  |  005   |30102011 | 837437  | Y       | Y       |         | No     |
          ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I iterate based on this specific range from excel in Java? I saw this CellReference in Apache POI but not sure how I should be using this. Let's assume that the paths etc has been declared something like

(Updated: I have found a way that could possibly save all the lines of data, by using StringBuffer)

```
public void prepareExcel(InputStream excel){
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(excel);            
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
        Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);

        for (int cn = 5; cn < 23; cn++) {
            Cell c = r.getCell(cn);
            sb.append(c);
         }
    }   
}
```

The next question would be, how do I change this StringBuffer into saving to an object, and afterward to an ArrayList?
Or is there any better way to do this?

Assume Row H is nullable.

The Object is not so crucial here, we can assume:

```
public class SaveObject{
    private String rowC; 
    private String rowD;
private String rowE;
private String rowF;
private String rowG;
private String rowH;
private String rowI;
public String getRowC() {
    return rowC;
}
public void setRowC(String rowC) {
    this.rowC = rowC;
}
public String getRowD() {
    return rowD;
}
public void setRowD(String rowD) {
    this.rowD = rowD;
}
public String getRowE() {
    return rowE;
}
public void setRowE(String rowE) {
    this.rowE = rowE;
}
public String getRowF() {
    return rowF;
}
public void setRowF(String rowF) {
    this.rowF = rowF;
}
public String getRowG() {
    return rowG;
}
public void setRowG(String rowG) {
    this.rowG = rowG;
}
public String getRowH() {
    return rowH;
}
public void setRowH(String rowH) {
    this.rowH = rowH;
}
public String getRowI() {
    return rowI;
}
public void setRowI(String rowI) {
    this.rowI = rowI;
}
}
```

Comment: give your starting point... and you can find the last row using getRows() function (at least thats the function in JXL there might be a similar function in POI). Use for(int i=startingValue;i<sheet.getRows();i++) // your code

Comment: TheLostMind, my start point is row 6 as stated above. Specifically, C6.

Comment: @progricebowl Check this about how to use Cell Reference using apache4 POI. Hope this will definitely help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/17588011/624003

Comment: To explain further there is someone who wanted to write data via a loop (based on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226194/java-apache-poi-trouble-filling-rows-and-cells-with-loops-excel), while I wanted to read data.

Comment: This will also be useful for some idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479882/how-to-store-values-from-excel-to-some-collection-in-java
Now I don't know how to save it into objects.

Comment: What setters does your object provide?

Comment: Hi, please see the above for the update. Thanks :D